# dotnet-project-licenses --version shows wrong version any ideas why?

Tags: .net, nuget

I try to use the dotnet-project-licenses project from github.
Installation completed successfull but as described [here](https://www.andreashennig.com/blog/collect-license-information-in-a-dotnet-application/):
should show me the following version:

> dotnet-project-licenses --version
>
> NugetUtility 2.3.11

Now to me it shows NugetUtility 0.0.0.0 which for sure is wrong.

I did some research and also asked chatGPT but after updating/installing nuget and trying to update the dotnet-project-licenses project itself it did still show me the wrong version number.

Does anyone have an idea, what could be the reason?

Comment: yep, repro here too; I suggest reporting it [here](https://github.com/tomchavakis/nuget-license/issues)